# NFS Server not responding when Mac is mounting

Tags: ubuntu, mac-osx, nfs, mac

I've setup a NFS Server on a Ubuntu 18.04 machine. The problem is when I mount it on a MacBook Pro, and move files from Mac's disk to the mounted foulder, the system freezes.

Looking at the logs on the server site through vim `/var/log/messages` i see this error:Dun

```
lockd: server MacBook-Pro.local not responding, timed out
```

Here's my exports file:

```
/storage/public *(rw,async,no_subtree_check,insecure)
```

Does someone know what could it be?

Comment: Try to mount with nfs v3. OSX has a bug in v4.

Comment: Hello @kofemann, thanks for your answer. I tried to mount with v3, but got the same error.